# CSS transition property overrides jQuery animation time on SVG element

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I have a nice little SVG element that I animate on by growing it from 0px-70px.
This element is also a button that has a nice stroke animation on hover. My problem is that the CSS transition property that is used for the stroke animation affects the timing of how fast the element grows when it appears. I don't want my hover animation to go too fast but the appear animation is way too slow.

HTML:

```
<svg width="141" height="141" >
    <rect rx="3" y="-50" x="50" width="0" height="0" transform="rotate(45)" fill="white"   class="timeline-button">
    </rect>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
$("rect").animate({
  width: "50%",
  height: "50%"
},100);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbELqY

Is there any way to work around this, besides changing the transition property manually with jquery? This is an annoying solution because the button will be constantly animated and interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured this one out really easily. 
I was animating 'all' using the css transition property. 
Instead of animating all, i just specified what I needed to animate so i changed it from:

```
transition: 2s all ease;
```

to:

```
transition: stroke-dasharray 1s, stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, ease;
```

These properties were not affected by the jQuery animate command so they remained seperate from each other. 
I am unsure though, what needs to be done if I needed to animate the stroke-width for example.